# Javascript DOMException: The associated Track is in an invalid state

Tags: javascript, domexception, mediadevices

I'm trying to create a photo capture web app on a nodeJS server, and i'm using the *javascript* code below.

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
  .then(gotMedia)
  .catch(error => console.error('getUserMedia() error:', error));

  event.preventDefault()
})
```

And the gotMedia function is this:

```
function gotMedia(mediaStream) {
    const mediaStreamTrack = mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0];
    const imageCapture = new ImageCapture(mediaStreamTrack);
    console.log(imageCapture);

    const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    // ...
    imageCapture.grabFrame()
    .then(imageBitmap => {
        canvas.width = imageBitmap.width;
        canvas.height = imageBitmap.height;
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(imageBitmap, 0, 0);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('grabFrame() error:', error));
}
```

Everything works fine, the image capturing is ok, but an error occurs, when i snap photos rapidly one after another, that says:

> grabFrame() error: DOMException: The associated Track is in an invalid state.

This usually happens when i capture too many photos (like clicking rapidly for about more than 20 seconds), but it also has happened on the first five snapshots. Does anyone know what's going on and what should i change, in order to fix this? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the exact same thing. I wouldn't mind the exception if it didn't appear to kill the video stream permanently as well, even if caught.

Comment: Unfortunately i haven't found any solution yet, but i'm still trying to figure this out and if i make it, i'll let u know

Comment: hi, I am also running into the exact same thing. The loop starts to take photos every 20 seconds using the same function, after a series of photos taken, it starts to throw this (The associated Track is in an invalid state) error. How should we fix the invalid state? Any one of you succeeded to come up with a solution for this? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

According to the [spec](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-image/index.html#dom-imagecapture-grabframe) such error could be result of not acceptable state. In chromium sources I have found [this method](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/0e630cf2c14d1e0c815c95a8710e4d6eb5e09736/third_party/WebKit/Source/modules/imagecapture/ImageCapture.cpp#31).

I've overcame error using code like this:

```
  const promise = getPrevImagePromise();

  if (!promise && !(imageCapture.track.readyState != 'live' || !imageCapture.track.enabled || imageCapture.track.muted)) {
    const imagePromise = imageCapture.grabFrame()
      .then((image) => {
        // do work with image
      })
      .then(() => {
        deletePrevImagePromise()
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // 
      });

    setPrevImagePromise(imagePromise);
  }
```

Comment: You saved my day. Checking for `readyState` was is mandatory on my application before calling `grabFrame()`.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and was unable to get the bleeding-edge `grabFrame` function to work reliably.

Instead, you can draw from an intermediate video source. In your function, that would look something like this (untested):

```
function gotMedia(mediaStream) {
    const mediaStreamTrack = mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0];
    const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    const video = document.createElement('video');

    video.autoplay = true;
    video.srcObject = mediaStream;
    video.onplay = () => {
         canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
         canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
         canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);
    };
}
```

Of course, if you're going to be capturing a lot of frames, it'd be best to create a single video alongside the stream and to capture from that each time.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

```js
let preview = document.getElementById('preview')
let recording = document.getElementById('recording')
let photo = document.getElementById('photo')
let photoButton = document.getElementById('photoButton')
let imageHolder = document.getElementById('image-holder')

async function startWebcam() {
  return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true
  })
};

photoButton.addEventListener('click', async() => {
  let webcamStream = await startWebcam()
  preview.srcObject = webcamStream
  const track = webcamStream.getVideoTracks()[0]
  const imageCapture = new ImageCapture(track)
  const bitmap = await imageCapture.grabFrame()
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
  canvas.width = bitmap.width
  canvas.height = bitmap.height
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
  context.drawImage(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height)
  let image = canvas.toDataURL()
  imageHolder.innerHTML += `<img src="${image}"></img>`
  track.stop()

})
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Desktoprecord</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.0/css/bulma.min.css">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app4.js" defer></script>
</head>

<div class="container">
  <video id="preview" width="25%" height="auto" autoplay muted poster="https://placekitten.com/g/150"></video>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/320/261" id="photo" alt="photo">
  <div id="image-holder">
    To be replaced with pretty pictures
  </div>
  <video src="" id="preview"></video>
  </jdiv>
  <div class="buttons are-large">
    <button id="photoButton" class="button is-success"><i class="fas fa-camera"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Each time you are going to take a photo you start the camera and after you got the pic you have to stop the track

Answer (score 0):

I want to grabFrame() in a loop (reused without stop()), thanks to fomasha,
my code works as follow
`

```
async function aSleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(R => setTimeout(R, ms));
}
var prevP=null;
function getPrevImagePromise() {return prevP;}
function setPrevImagePromise(p) {prevP=p;}
function deletePrevImagePromise() {prevP=null;}
async function aRun() {
     imageCapture = new ImageCapture(gImageTrack);
  while(true) {
    const promise = getPrevImagePromise();
    if (!promise && !(imageCapture.track.readyState != 'live' || !imageCapture.track.enabled || imageCapture.track.muted)) {
    const imagePromise = imageCapture.grabFrame()
      .then((image) => {
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 640, 480);
      })
      .then(() => {
        deletePrevImagePromise()
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // 
      });
      setPrevImagePromise(imagePromise);
    }
    await aSleep(500);
  }
}
```

`
refactoring

`

```
function zCamera() {
    var T=this;
    T.aInit=async function() {
        T.mStm=await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { width: 4096, height: 3200, facingMode: 'environment' } });
        T.mTrk=T.mStm.getTracks()[0];
        T.mCap=new ImageCapture(T.mTrk);
    }
    T.getSetting=function() {
        return T.mTrk.getSettings();
    }
    T.aGrabFrame=async function() {
      var P=new Promise((R)=>{
        T.mCap.grabFrame().then((vImg) => {
          R(vImg);
        }).catch((error) => {
          R(null);
        });
      });
      return P;    
    }
}
var gContext;
var oCamera;
async function aInitCamera()
{
    var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
    gContext=canvas.getContext('2d');
    oCamera=new zCamera();
    await oCamera.aInit();
}
async function aRun() {
    while(true) {
        var wImg=await oCamera.aGrabFrame();
        if (wImg!=null)
            gContext.drawImage(wImg, 0, 0, 640, 480);
        await aSleep(100);
    }
}
async function jMain() {
    await aInitCamera();
    aRun();
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

The error has gone when I clone the track

```
function(){
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(stream => {
            const track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0]

            const imageCapture = new ImageCapture(track.clone())

            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('bitmaprenderer')

            setInterval(() => {
                if (track.readyState === 'live')
                    imageCapture.grabFrame().then((bmp: ImageBitmap) => {

                        canvas.height = bmp.height
                        canvas.width = bmp.width
                        ctx.transferFromImageBitmap(bmp)

                        new Promise(res => canvas.toBlob(res)).then((blob) =>
                            imageRef.current.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob as MediaSource))

                    }).catch(err => { console.log(err) })

            }, 1000)

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).